# Display "back to top" button only if there is enough text in the text DIV

Tags: php, css

My website uses PHP and CSS. I am looking for a solution to display a back to top button, but only if the content DIV has enough text so the user needs to scroll down, then click the button to back up.

Is this possible without javascript?

I can place such a button, click it to go to the top of the content DIV, but if there is not enough text to fill the entire content DIV for high resolutions (higher than 1920x1080), the button looks silly as it has no use and there is not enough text to fill the content DIV.

I can manually hide the button with the display: hidden; line, but setting the class of the button to one of three states (normal vs. hide for higher resolutions vs. hide for much higher resolutions) is tedious.

In short, how can I set something up like "If length of text/size of text > height of content div, then display back to top button"?

Playing around with DIVs and CSS

Comment: My first thought would be to listen to a scroll event on a the document. If that happens, then you (probably) know that the text is longer than then viewport.

Comment: Thanks, but is this possible without JS? Just with CSS and PHP?

Answer (score 0):

While it's challenging to achieve this without using JavaScript for dynamic calculations based on the content size and scroll position, you can still make it more flexible using pure CSS for a responsive design. One approach is to use media queries combined with the :empty and :before pseudo-elements to conditionally display the "back to top" button. However, this solution assumes that your content is within a specific container.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that I am a noob that can only copy and paste code snippets. 

My website uses media queries...for different resolutions:

@media only screen  and (min-width: x px) and (min-height: y px) -> Resolution 1...and different manually set designs...with a static background. The CSS sets the menu, the content div etc. .. my websites are www.seelenpuls.at and www.grummelgnom.at ... it's PHP and CSS, but no true responsive design, but fixed background and DIVs. + extra designs for mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Please check my code how I implement this on my website

```js
const rootElement = document.documentElement;
const upToTopBtn = document.getElementById("up-to-top");

function scrollToTop() {
  rootElement.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth",
  });
}

function showBtn() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 100 || rootElement.scrollTop > 100) {
    upToTopBtn.classList.add("active");
  } else {
    upToTopBtn.classList.remove("active");
  }
}

document.addEventListener("scroll", showBtn);
upToTopBtn.addEventListener("click", scrollToTop);
```

```css
$lightBlue-900-dark: #003c6c;
$lightBlue-900: #01579b;
$lightBlue-700: #0091ea;
$dark-blue: #111c31;

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
body {
  background-color: #111c31;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  height: 3000px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(135deg, $dark-blue, $lightBlue-700);
  font-family: arial;
}
h1,
h2 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
#up-to-top {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: $lightBlue-900-dark;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 40px;
  right: 25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 25px rgba(0, 0, 85, 0.5);
  transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;

  span {
    max-width: 35px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in-out;

    img {
      object-fit: cover;
      object-position: center;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 30px rgba(0, 0, 17, 0.8);
    background-color: $lightBlue-900;

    span {
      transform: rotate(-360deg);
    }
  }
}

.active {
  visibility: visible !important;
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

```html
<h1>Back to top Button</h1>
<h2>Scroll to Down</h2>


<div id="up-to-top">
  <span><img src="https://i.ibb.co/5krn9rB/arrow-up.png" alt="" height="20"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: He specifically states he wants to do this without javascript

Comment: Thank you! If it is only possible with JS, I am fine with this. Thank you. :)

Comment: Ranjeet, your code starts right away. Where do I put it? Isn't there anything missing above "const rootElement = document.documentElement;
const upToTopBtn = document.getElementById("up-to-top");"? 

Does all go into the same PHP file?